# Table disappear when I use sideways command

Tags: tables, rotating

I want to rotate a table,  When I use sideways table environment table disappears from the document and also disappear from list of tables. I tried a lot with different possible packages as below. I need the whole table environment(label, caption etc) to rotate.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
   \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
   \usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.25in, right=0.75in]{geometry}
                 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
                 \usepackage{amsmath}
                 \usepackage{csvsimple}
                 \usepackage{amssymb}
                 \usepackage{longtable}
                 \usepackage{booktabs}
                 \usepackage{adjustbox}
                 \usepackage{placeins}
                 \usepackage{float}
                 \usepackage{wrapfig}
                 \usepackage{array}
                 \usepackage{tabularx}
                 \usepackage{tabu}
                 \usepackage{setspace} 
                 \usepackage{multirow} 
                 \usepackage{rotating}
                 \usepackage{multirow}
                 \usepackage{longtable}

                 \usepackage{enumitem}
                 \usepackage{pifont}
                 \usepackage{natbib}
                 \usepackage{booktabs}
                 \usepackage{collcell}
                 \usepackage{datatool}
                 \usepackage{pdflscape}
                 \usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Set table like this}
    \vspace{2mm}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}\toprule
        &       & Data set 1 &       &       & Data set 2 &       &       & Data set 3 &  \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10}
        Estimators & $ n=10 $  & $ n=15 $  & $ n=20 $  & n=10  & $ n=15 $  & $ n=20 $  & $ n=10 $  & $ n=15 $  & $ n=20 $\\ \midrule
        $ \hat{M}_{01} $   & 100.451 & 101.658 & 100.012 & 103.402 & 119.517 & 311.625 & 110.256 & 126.864 & 157.835 \\
        $ \hat{M}_{02} $   & 59.146 & 7407.001 & 1508.683 & 448.119 & 326.131 & 788.717 & 189.374 & 153.392 & 285.499 \\
        $ \hat{M}_{03} $   & 2896.694 & 2828.759 & 1154.403 & 974.536 & 1931.318 & 12350 & 1150.055 & 2778.052 & 1245.779 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tex table}%
\end{sidewaystable}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't  think you have to use `[H]` for sideways table, as it puts the table on a page of its own.

Comment: I added some notes about `[H]` to my answer

Comment: @Bernard - Not only does the `[H]` option not "have to be" used when using `sidewaystable` environments, it *must not* be used. David's answer and comments reveals this issue in more detail.

Comment: Yes its works when i remove [H]. Bundle of thanks to all of you... @DavidCarlisle, Bernard, Mico

Answer (score 4):

You don't show what you did so it is not possible to say what is wrong with that, but if you change `\begin{table}[H]` to `\begin{sidewaystable}` and change `\end{table}` to `\end{sidewaystable}` then you get

[image]

---

If you use `[H]` on `sidewaystable` *without* using the `float` package then you get an error

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'.
```

However when the float package is loaded `H` gets allowed in the optional argument but doesn't actually work for `sidewaystable` which causes the text to be silently dropped, which is not ideal.

One could argue  whether this is a failing in the `rotating` or `float` package but since I only have write access to `rotating` I'll say it is an issue with `float`. I'll ping its maintainer....

Comment: I tried it with  \begin{sidewaystable} and  \end{sidewaystable} but it's not working, still disappears the table

Comment: @IbrahimM text should never disappear without warning. First fix your question so that it has an example of the _problem_ not an example of a document that does not use `sidewaystable` at all, and then show the log file from the example document so we see what warnings are given.

Comment: @IbrahimM No you did not try it as above you tried it with `[H]` which is not a legal option.

Comment: @Mico well I added some text to relate to the question after the question was edited. I don't think it's enough just to say you shouldn't use H (H should have worked, or latex should give an error).

Comment: Nicely worded addendum!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  the log written on 1st row is in parenthesis ( Label `tab:addlabel' multiply defined ).

Comment: @IbrahimM there is not even one label tab:addlabel' in this document so clearly it does not give that error. If your real document has that error you presumably have duplicated label, but that is unrelated to this question.

Comment: With `sidewaystable` the contents is typeset and boxed with `lrbox`. But the `H` option causes this to be performed inside a `\vbox` and, when `\end{sidewaystable}` is found, first the `\vbox` is closed, then the box register `\rot@float@box` is delivered, but it's empty, by now.

Answer (score 4):

What happens is roughly the following:

1. `sidewaystable` is essentially similar to `table`, with the difference that instead of executing `\@float{table}[<pref>]` it does

   ```
   \@float{table}[<pref>]\begin{lrbox}{\rot@float@box}
   ```
2. when `\end{sidewaystable}` is found, `\end{lrbox}` is done, followed by some maintenance jobs and eventually by `\end@float`.

In the above code, `<pref>` stands for the explicit positioning preferences or the default ones.

In the case of `\begin{sidewaystable}[H]`, TeX will find

```
\@float{table}[H]\begin{lrbox}{\rot@float@box}
```

and now `float` kicks in. It changes `\@float` to examine the options; if `H` is found, it does

```
\@float@HH{sidewaystable}[H]
```

which gobbles `[H]`, does some maintenance jobs among which redefining `\endsidewaystable` to be `\float@endH` and starts setting a `\vbox` in the register `\@currbox`.

At the moment `\end{sidewaystable}` is scanned, there are two boxes being formed: `\rot@float@box` and `\@currbox`. Since `\begin{lrbox}` does clever tricks with grouping, the box is finished up and after it also `\@currbox`. But the code of the standard `\endsidewaystable` that should rotate the box is never executed (and would have no effect anyway, because at the closure of `\@currbox`, the box saved in `\rot@float@box` is lost as the register's contents is restored to what it contained before the start of `\vbox\@currbox` (that is, empty).

Solution: it doesn't make sense to use `[H]` with `sidewaystable`.

I'd say even more: a `sidewaystable` should be avoided as long as possible and it should always be a page float. Setting it as a top float, for instance, would force the reader to do awkward movements for looking at the table; besides, if a `sidewaystable` fits as a top float, it would most likely fit as a standard (unrotated) `table`.

Comment: +1 for "it doesn't make sense to use `[H]` with `sidewaystable`". :-)

Answer (score 2):

Works for me. I took the opportunity to use  `siunitx` for an alignment of numeric volumns on the decimal dot, and load caption for a correct vertical spacing between caption and table without having to specify `\vspace{2mm}`, and corrected some errors/inconsistencies. In particular, as pointed by @David Carlisle, the `[H]` specifier should not be used with `sidewaystable`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1.25in, right=0.75in]{geometry}
             \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
             \usepackage{amsmath}
             \usepackage{csvsimple}
             \usepackage{amssymb}
             \usepackage{longtable}
             \usepackage{booktabs}
             \usepackage{adjustbox}
             \usepackage{placeins}
             \usepackage{float}
             \usepackage{wrapfig}
             \usepackage{array}
             \usepackage{tabularx}
            \usepackage{tabu}
             \usepackage{setspace}
             \usepackage{multirow}
             \usepackage{rotating}
             \usepackage{longtable}

             \usepackage{enumitem}
             \usepackage{pifont}
             \usepackage{natbib}
             \usepackage{booktabs}
             \usepackage{collcell}
             \usepackage{datatool}
             \usepackage{pdflscape}
             \usepackage{graphicx}
            \usepackage{siunitx} %
            \usepackage{caption} %

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}%[H]
    \centering\sisetup{table-format =4.3, table-number-alignment=center}
    \caption{Set table like this}
    \begin{tabular}{c*{9}{S}}\toprule
        & & {Data set 1} & & & {Data set 2} & & & {Data set 3} & \\ %\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10}
        Estimators & {$n=10 $} & {$ n=15 $} & {$ n=20 $} & {n=10} & {$ n=15 $} & {$ n=20 $} & {$ n=10 $} & {$ n=15 $} & {$ n=20 $}\\ \midrule
        $ \hat{M}_{01} $ & 100.451 & 101.658 & 100.012 & 103.402 & 119.517 & 311.625 & 110.256 & 126.864 & 157.835 \\
        $ \hat{M}_{02} $ & 59.146 & 7407.001 & 1508.683 & 448.119 & 326.131 & 788.717 & 189.374 & 153.392 & 285.499 \\
        $ \hat{M}_{03} $ & 2896.694 & 2828.759 & 1154.403 & 974.536 & 1931.318 & 12350 & 1150.055 & 2778.052 & 1245.779 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \label{tex table}%
\end{sidewaystable}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While certainly nifty in terms of using the `S` column type for the 9 data columns, your answer doesn't address the OP's main problem, viz., the disappearance of the entire table. You may want to add a sentence (and/or make a cross-reference to David C.'s answer) to note that the `[H]` location specifier *must not* be used with `sidewaystable` environments.

Comment: @Mico: Done; I contented myself with commenting the specifier, but you're right: what goes well without saying, goes even better when you say it.